# ActiveRecord Querying associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an event model with many slots(from and to, both datetime attributes).

Say I have the below events

Event 1 - slot 1 (to and from: yesterday)
        - slot 2 (to and from: tomorrow)

Event 2 - slot 3 (to and from: yesterday)

Now i need to - say get only past events. - just Event 2.

When I query

```
Event.joins(:time_slots).where('time_slots.to < ?', DateTime.current)
```

since slot 1, qualifies I get Event 1 too for the past events which is not valid.

How can I just get Event 2, i.e only if all associations are true, return if ALL true and not ANY.

## EDIT 1

The result should be an ActiveRecord::Relation as I need to perform further operations to it.

```
Event.joins(:time_slots)
  .public_send(filter_by)
  .search(params[:query])
  .sorted(direction)
  .page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Maybe that but not really good ... `Event.joins(:time_slots).select{ |event| event.time_slots.sort_by(&:to).last.to < DateTime.current }`

Comment: @mudasobwa That would get me proper time slots but I need events here and when I get events for those slots, i get Event 1 too.

Comment: @RonanLouarn Thanks, That does return the past events but the result should be an AR and not an array as I need to perform further AR operations on the result. My bad. I didn't mention that. Updating question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest spelling is probably:

```
Event.where.not(id: TimeSlot.current_or_future.select(:event_id))
```

with a scope defined on TimeSlot:

```
scope :current_or_future, -> { where(to: DateTime.current..DateTime::Infinity) }
```

Comment: N.B. in the upcoming Ruby versions (2.6+) you won't necessarily need the `DateTime::Infinity`, i.e. `(DateTime.current..)`. More on that [here](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/rubys-new-infinite-range-syntax-0-97777cf06270).